# Can we use rems to style a component in react native

Tags: css, react-native

I want to use `rem`s for styling as I normally do in other CSS projects. But I don't understand how to get this working. This doesn't seem to work at all.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    fontSize: 3rem,
    fontWeight: 400
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can!  Using [this](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet) npm package you can easily do.

**STEPS**

1. run `npm i react-native-extended-stylesheet --save`
2. Define styles using `EStyleSheet.create()` instead of `StyleSheet.create():`

Simple Example :

```
/* component.js */
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';

// define extended styles 
const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  column: {
    width: '80%'                                    // 80% of screen width
  },
  text: {
    color: '$textColor',                            // global variable $textColor
    fontSize: '1.5rem'                              // relative REM unit
  },
  '@media (min-width: 350) and (max-width: 500)': { // media queries
    text: {
      fontSize: '2rem',
    }
  }
});

// use styles as usual
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.column}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This implies that `rem` is not accepted by default ("native" RN), like `percentage` and `pixels` right?

Comment: @Felix you are correct, `rem` is not a supported layout prop, per the [RN docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#height), only points or percentages are. Same with the [Text style props](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#fontsize), for fontSize only points are supported.